# Prolog dot product with variables (constraint satisfaction)

Tags: prolog, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I'm working on a prolog assignment and I'm currently very very close to the solution.  So, the problem is a constraint satisfaction problem where I have to find values for a set of variables such that certain conditions are true.  Specifically, given 3 words (W1,W2,W3), assign their variables such that W1+W2=W3.  An example of this would be SEND+MORE=MONEY, or IT+IS=ME.

The constraints are: (1) they have to add up correctly, (2) the starting letter cannot be 0 (3) and all variables must be distinct.  And it has to work for a general word problem.  My issue is happening when I try to ensure that they add up correctly (I've met the other conditions and I understand the problem).  In terms of the second word problem we should have:

```
 10*I + 1*T
+10*I + 1*S
___________
 10*M + 1*E
```

So, I have made a function that makes lists of powers of 10 in a certain length, like so:

```
powlist(1,L) :-
    append([1.0],[],L). 
powlist(N,L) :-
    N1 is N-1,
    X is 10**N1,
    powlist(N1,L1),
    append([X],L1,L),
    !.
```

I also have the actual list of letters, say, [I,T,I,S,M,E].  I then constructed a list of coefficients (I'll explain that part later) out of powlist so we have something like the following: [10,1,10,1,-10,-1].  I did this so if we took the dot product between this list of coefficients and the list of letters, and it was zero, the constraint would be satisfied.  But, I can't get this dot product theory to work.  I currently have a line that says:

```
   scalar_product(Coefficients, Letters, #=, 0)
```

But this is giving me the following error:

! Instantiation error in argument 2 of is/2
! goal:  _102 is 0+10.0*_109

I'm not sure how to define dot product so it can work on variables (instead of just atoms).  All of the rest of the code works perfectly (and I don't want to put it on here because this is a very common question for introductory prolog courses, and I don't want to give lazy people answers).  What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy is indeed sound and does work, at least with SWI-Prolog CLP(FD) using the built-in [`scalar_product/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html#scalar_product/4). I am unfamiliar with the definition of this predicate in SICStus, but it's interface appears to be the same as in SWI-Prolog.

I can make a couple of suggestions. Firstly, perhaps some aspect of the code you've written is generating choicepoints which, when executed in backtracking (e.g., to seek alternate solutions, such as via [`label/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html#label/1)), the interpreter executes the subgoal `_102 is 0+10.0*_109` where `_109` is unintentionally unbound. Have you written a predicate which contains such a line? Even if not, I recommend double checking your code to ensure that they do not generate unnecessary choicepoints, such as your definition of `powlist/2`. I recommend that you try the following instead:

```
powlist(1, [1]) :- !.
powlist(N, [F|Fs]) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N - 1,
    F is 10 ** N1,
    powlist(N1, Fs).
```

This version leaves no choicepoints for the Prolog interpreter to backtrack to, which *might* resolve the problem (though, without seeing more code, I simply can't tell).

Otherwise, if you are correct and the error is indeed emanating from within the definition of `scalar_product/4` (though I'd be surprised), then perhaps you could generate the scalar product constraint term and add it to the store yourself, manually. For example, consider:

```
my_scalar_product([V|Vs], [C|Cs], Op, Value) :-
    construct_constraint(Vs, Cs, (V * C), Constr),
    Constraint =.. [Op, Constr, Value],
    Constraint.

construct_constraint([], [], Acc, Acc).
construct_constraint([V|Vs], [F|Fs], Acc, Res) :-
    construct_constraint(Vs, Fs, '+'(Acc, (V * F)), Res).
```

This version (`my_scalar_product/4`) assumes the same interface as the built-in `scalar_product/4`, but it adds the constraint to the store instead of attempting to execute it using `is/2`.